# How to retrieve table header data within <a> tag using Javascript or Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

How can I retrieve table header data within `<a>` tag such as `Name` using jQuery or JavaScript?

My html is:

```
<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <th><a href="www.a.com">Name<a></th>
        <th colspan="2">Telephone</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Bill Gates</td>
        <td>555 77 854</td>
        <td>555 77 855</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I am not able to see your JavaScript code.

Comment: `document.querySelector('a').text` will do so....

Comment: Thank you Rory for editing. I was not sure how to write html block. And also thanks to all for your answering. Now I am getting lots of way to retrieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether I get your question right, but shouldn't the following work?

```
$('th').find('a').each(function(){console.log($(this).text())});
```

-> Result in your case `Name`

```
<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <th><a href="www.a.com">Name<a></th>
        <th><a href="www.a1.com">Name1<a></th>
        <th><a href="www.a2.com">Name2<a></th>
        <th><a href="www.a3.com">Name3<a></th>
        <th colspan="2">Telephone</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Bill Gates</td>
        <td>555 77 854</td>
        <td>555 77 855</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

-> Result is:

```
Name
Name1
Name2
Name3
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Jquery you can use the selector

```
$('table tr th a').html()
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/puvzt30g/)

Answer (score 0):

I would give your link tag and ID, then use:

```
document.getElementByID(linkID).href;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$("table tr th a").text();` or `$("table tr th a").html();`